# QR Decoding won't work with ZXing and Aforge

Tags: c#, .net, zxing, aforge

I've got a little problem with ZXing.net... I dosen't work !

Maybe I use it incorrectly, but I search, search, search, nothing seems to work... I use WindowsForms. I want to read my QR Code thought my camera. I use another library called AForge. This one works perfectly ; My camera shows up and works like a charm ! But when I want to read a QR Code, it dosen't work...

So maybe someone will be able to help me ... ?

```
//When I load my form, I start the camera
private void FrmConnexion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // enumerate video devices
    videoSources = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

    // create video source
    videoStream = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoSources[0].MonikerString);

    // set NewFrame event handler
    videoStream.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(videoSource_NewFrame);

    // start the video source
    videoStream.Start();
} 

//Every new frame of the video
void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    try
    {
        streamBitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        safeTempstreamBitmap = (Bitmap)streamBitmap.Clone();
        Pic_Camera.Image = streamBitmap;
        Pic_Camera.Refresh();

        //Where I decome my QR Code.
        Result result = barcodeReader.Decode(streamBitmap);
        //To see my result, I register my result into a Label.
        Lbl_Identifiant.Text = "{result?.Text}";
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Console.Write(exp.Message);
    }
}
```

I think I didn't forget anything..

Thanks for your help !

Comment: First, welcome.  I'm fairly new at using ZXing too, but when you say it doesn't work, does that mean NO barcodes are recognized, or just QR?  Also, it would  be typical for "NewFrame" callback to happen many times, and the result will often be "null" if it cannot decode.  So your code should probably have a "if (result == null) return" or something, I think.  Also, I have found PC cameras to be difficult to use for this -- you may need to change lighting, focus, angle, etc.

Comment: Litteraly nothing happends. My Label dosen't change ! I tried to add a condition with a if... nothing. I will seek again though the docs, for the XX time...

Comment: Are you sure videoSource_NewFrame() is being called?

Comment: Did you try the demo application of zxing.net which uses AForge?
https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/tree/master/Clients/AForgeDemo

Is there any exception caught?

In my opinion the line `Lbl_Identifiant.Text = "{result?.Text}";` should be changed to `if (result != null) Lbl_Identifiant.Text = "{result.Text}";` because if one frame can be decoded and the following not it would instantly overwrite the text of the label.